# Next Js 13.5.6 not creating build Folder

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Not able to create build Folder in Next.js 13.5 through npm run build. And want to upload this next js project in GoDaddy cpanel. It's dynamic project.

Comment: it's creating out folder but for static content. not for Dynamic content. So, What to do for Dynamic content

Answer (score 0):

Now after update it creates an **out** folder. you can create it into a zip file and can upload to the server by just uploading it

Comment: it's creating out folder but for static content. not for Dynamic content. So, What to do for Dynamic content